# action button does not seem to do anything when i click on it

Tags: oracle-apex

Hello Oracle apex gurus.

i have a a problem in my oders page for my project. when i try to use the action button in my interactive report in the report details it doesn't work. this is not the first time i had this problem. i already asked my co-workers and i searched it on the internet what do i need to do to fix this issue?

[this is the page in my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7tuE.png)

[this is the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11wM3.png)

[i get this error when i click the action button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU2zN.png)

Comment: Question is: "when i try to use the action button in my interactive report in the report details it doesn't work" >>> what does it mean, "it doesn't work"? What happens when you press the "Actions" button? Which Apex version do you use?

Comment: well when i press the action button on the interactive report i will not show me the action menu. it just doesn't come down.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when there is a javascript error on the page. Open the browser console and check for errors. Also, the red triangle in the development toolbar tells you something is wrong and you need to check the console:

[image]

Comment: i have edited the question to include the error i get when i click the action button.

Comment: What could be causing the javascript error ? Do you any custom javascript on the page ? Are you able to reproduce this at will on any other new page ? The error isn't saying much you'll have to do debugging yourself...

Comment: i have no javascript in this page

Comment: From the "editor" picture it shows that "customer_id" is a plugin or am I mistaken ? Any changes if you don't use that plugin ? That could be the cause. As I said... debug... try recreating the page from scratch in a copy of the app, see at what point the error starts happening.